# Powershell gci/rename limited to 33 items

Tags: powershell

I'm not sure why, but when using the following code, it loops indefinitely, adding the word "small-" to the beginning of each file repeatedly.

If I change 1..34 to 1..33, it only iterates once, as expected.  In fact, it works for any number under 34, but breaks for 34 and up.

Is this a bug or just some oddity of the code I'm not understanding?

```
$dir = '.\Desktop\chroot\testbed\'

# File Generator
rm $dir\*
foreach ($i in (1..34)){
    New-Item $dir\File-$i.txt -type file
}

gci $dir | Rename-Item -NewName {"Small- " + $_.Name}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "breaks"? Does it throw an exception? What is the "broken" behavior?

Comment: I clarified the description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not sure why, but when using the following code, it loops indefinitely, adding the word "small-" to the beginning of each file repeatedly.

Because you keep adding files that appear after the last file in the folder. `gci | rename` doesn't wait until all objects are collected and then pipe them.  It starts streaming objects as soon as they appear.  You keep adding "new" objects that `gci` finds and adds to the pipeline.  You've created a feedback loop.

My guess is that you can fix it by doing this:

```
$files = gci $dir
$files | Rename-Item -NewName {"Small- " + $_.Name}
```

Or coincidentally fix it by doing this:

```
gci $dir | sort | Rename-Item -NewName {"Small- " + $_.Name}
```

The first one establishes the collection and then streams *just those files*.  In the second one, `sort` waits until it has the entire collection before passing it on (it has to in order to sort the collection).

Why does it do it at 34?  My guess is that it has to do with how your directory's content table is organized, or there's possibly a race condition between `rename` and `gci`.

Comment: The second option works beautifully.  Your variables are inconsistent in the first one, by the way (for posterity).